# How to dynamically add parameters to every URL with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, jquery-mobile

I would like to add filtering to a "select category" page. E.g. "show only results with photos". The page consists out of multiple jQuery pages that allow a selection of the category within 3 levels. On the top I would like to add the form fields which should alter the href URL inside the pages upon select.

e.g.:
[image]

Is it possible to alter the URL of every single a href tag and not just one of them?

Answer (score 1):

So something like this?

And this is just pseudo code - haven't tested it

Essentially, we use the `a` selector to get all the anchors.

We then call on jquery's `each` function.

And within the function we read the links (`$(this)`) href and set it to the same + a query string.

This is just a very short example. You might need to do various checks.

```
$('a').each(function(){
  $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?my=qstring');
});
```

*Little update*

OP wanted to know how to put this in a function to call at anytime.

Something like:

```
function updateUrls(){
  // you might want to target urls in a given div, so something like
  $('#myULOfUrls a').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href') + '?my=qstring');
  });
}
```

Then in your form-change, you simple call `updateUrls()`

Comment: Yes, this might go into right direction. How could I bind it to a change event. I would like to have that function executed every time the user changes the forms in the filter section.